# PHP:my session_variables shows when the page refresh

Tags: php, session-variables

I know this is very simple thing but i am not aware of this. I have php code on same page for a signup form which have some session variables to be shown when any condition matches with the code.

The code structure is like this:

```
      <?php
         session_start();
         if(isset($_POST['signup'])
       {
      if(condition)
       {
          $_SESSION['err1']="string";
       }
     else
       {
           $_SESSION['err2']="string";
       }
     }

     ?>

                 //HTML form
    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['err1']) {?>
    <li><?php echo $_SESSION['err1'];}?></li>

    <?php if(isset($_SESSION['err2']) {?>
    <li><?php echo $_SESSION['err2'];}?></li>


                 //rest of the form
```

I have more block of if-else in my code. Initially, when an condition is matched, the session message is shown. But as soon as the page refresh an another session message is shown along with previous session message.

Is this correct way of coding with forms? Because i want to show error messages inside the html form.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What forms? I don't see any form.

Comment: That's maybe because you do not empty your session variable.
Between 2 HTTP request, the session is kept on the server (juste reloading at each request).
So, if you are putting a message on `$_SESSION['error1']` for the first call, it will show it. Then, on the second load, if you are putting a message on `$_SESSION['error2']`, you will also have the message of `error1` because the session keep your data. After showing the form, you should empty all your session messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's maybe because you do not empty your session variable.

Between 2 HTTP request, the session is kept on the server (juste reloading at each request).

So, if you are putting a message on `$_SESSION['error1']` for the first call, it will show it. Then, on the second load, if you are putting a message on `$_SESSION['error2']`, you will also have the message of `error1` because the session keep your data.

After showing the form, you should empty all your session messages

Comment: should i empty it by with session_destroy or with other function?

Comment: You can empty with `unset($_SESSION['error1'])` and do it for all entries, or try to reset the entiere session `$_SESSION = array();`

Answer (score 0):

Simply unset your session variable after you echo.

```
<li><?php echo $_SESSION['err1'];} unset($_SESSION['err1']); ?></li>
```

Comment: and rate my question if found useful for some new beginners.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a bad example that use session to echo errors.

what i do many times at the starting of my php.

```
$errors = array(); // make a empty array errors before the conditional statements
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
      //handle your POST variable
      if(condition1){ 
          $errors[] = "some error";
      } 
      if(condition2) {
          $errors[] = "some another error";
      }
      //more conditions

     if (!empty($errors)) {
           //process your form data if there is no errro
     } else {
        //display back your form along with Errors
        if(isset($errors) && !empty($errors)) {

             foreach($errors as $error) {
                echo "<p class = 'error'>" . $error . "</p>";
              }
        }
        <form action = "" method = "POST">
           //your form elements
        </form>
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in first line of the php page, u can write
you can try  any of the three lines between if condition

```
if(isset($_SESSION))
{
unset($_SESSION); 
unregister($_SESSION['variable-name']) // try this also 
session_destroy();  //try this also 
}
```